# Principal value of $(\sqrt{2} +\sqrt{2}i)^{i+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Wolfram Alpha disagrees with my computation and my first guess is that is because a different branch cut is chosen, but this doesn't seem to be the case after checking, so I'm curious.

I have 
\begin{align}
(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2}i)^{1+i} &= \exp\big( (1+i) \ln \big( \sqrt{2}(1+i) \big) \big) \\
&= \exp \big( (1+i)\ln \big(2 e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}} \big) \big) \\
&= 2\exp \big( (1+i)\frac{\pi i}{4} \big) \\
&= \frac{2}{e^{\frac{\pi}{4}}}\exp \big( \frac{\pi i}{4} \big) .
\end{align}

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(sqrt(2)%20%2B%20sqrt(2)i)%5E(i%2B1)) however seems to compute an angle of $\theta = 84.7 ^\circ$, as opposed to $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4} = 45 ^\circ$.

The only freedom that we could have would be to pick a different branch $k$: $\ln(e^{\frac{\pi}{4} +2\pi k})$. But this shifts the the angle by $360 ^\circ$, so I'm really puzzled.

How would one reproduce Wolfram Alpha's answer? And more importantly, why do the results disagree? The choice of branch cut doesn't seem to make difference.

Comment: How did you factor the $2$ out of $\ln (2 exp \frac{i\pi}{2})$?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan I made a mistake. From the second line on, we should, indeed have \begin{align} \exp\(1+i) \ln \Big( 2 e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}} \big) \Big) &= \exp\Big( (1+i)\big( \ln(2) +\frac{i\pi}{4} \big) \Big) \\
&= \exp\Big( \big( \ln(2) - \frac{\pi}{4} \big)+i \big( \ln(2)+\frac{\pi}{4} \big) \Big) \\
&= \frac{2}{e^{\frac{\pi}{4}}} \exp i \Big(\ln(2) + \frac{\pi}{4} \Big) \end{align}

Comment: Okay.Why twice though?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan I intermediately pressed enter instead of Shift-enter, which left me only four minutes to write; in which I also made a few typos. Hence, the need for a new *finished* comment; which replaces the old one. :)

Comment: Okay :) I thought that you typed the message once, it did not appear and you had to type it again, only to find 2 answers. I suffered from the same situation, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take $\ln 2+\pi i/4$ as the principal logarithm of $\sqrt2(1+i)$.
Then
$$(1+i)\left(\ln 2+\frac{\pi i}4\right)
=\ln2-\frac\pi 4+i\left(\ln2+\frac {\pi}4\right).$$
The "principal value" you seek is the exponential of this.
Note that $\ln2+\pi/4$ radians is about $84.7$ degrees.